# Reference to static local varialble in C++

Tags: c++

I am not fully understanding how this piece of code works:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Foo {
    public:
        int a;
        static Foo& Instance() {
            static Foo instance;
            instance.a += 1;
            return instance;
        }
};

int main()
{
    auto foo1 = Foo::Instance();
    std::cout <<foo1.a << std::endl; //prints 1
    Foo::Instance().a += 1;
    std::cout <<foo1.a << std::endl; //prints 1
    auto foo2 = Foo::Instance();
    std::cout <<foo2.a << std::endl; //prints 4
}
```

My problem is the second cout. Since Instance is returning a reference to the static Foo I would expect that changing the static Foo would reflect to its reference `foo1`, but it looks like this is not the case. The behavior that `foo1` is having is something I would expect from a copy not a reference (I would have expected the 2nd cout to print 3). Is my understanding of references in C++ wrong? Or the problem is the `static` that is messing with me?

Comment: `foo1` is a copy. Try `auto& foo1` instead.

Comment: `foo1` and `foo2` are *copies* of the `Foo` object that `Instance()` returns a reference to, they are not references because `auto` does not deduce references. You need to use `auto&` instead. `Foo::Instance().a += 1;` is not making a copy, it uses the returned reference directly.

Comment: Side note : In general try to come up with a design that doesn't rely on singletons though.

Comment: Side note: if you intend for `Foo` to be a singleton, remember to disable the copy constructor and assignment operator to prevent accidental copies like this (as well as deliberate copies). In modern C++, you declare the copy constructor and assignment operator as `delete`ed. In older pre C++11 code the usual recommendation is to make the copy constructor and assignment operator `private` and not implement them.

Comment: I am going to assume that your minimal example above didn't bother showing the initialization of member `a` (but it's in your code).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your understanding of references in C++ is correct, but there's a subtle issue at play here that affects the output.

Let's go step by step through the code:

```cpp
auto foo1 = Foo::Instance();
```

At this line, `foo1` is not a reference; it's an object that is copy-constructed from the reference returned by `Foo::Instance()`. Since `auto` deduces the type without a reference, you get a new `Foo` object that is a copy of the `instance` inside `Foo::Instance()`. The copy has its `a` value as 1 because that's what `Instance()` set it to before returning.

```cpp
std::cout << foo1.a << std::endl; // prints 1
```

This prints `1` because `foo1.a` is 1 at this point, as expected.

```cpp
Foo::Instance().a += 1;
```

This line modifies the static instance inside `Instance()`. However, it does not affect `foo1` because `foo1` is a separate copy, not a reference to the instance.

```cpp
std::cout << foo1.a << std::endl; // prints 1
```

So when you print `foo1.a` again, it still prints `1` because `foo1` is not linked to the static instance inside `Instance()`.

```cpp
auto foo2 = Foo::Instance();
```

Here `foo2` is another object copy-constructed from the reference returned by `Instance()`. Since `Instance()` increments `a` every time it is called, and it was previously incremented in the `Foo::Instance().a += 1;` line, the static `instance` `a` value is now 3 before this line executes. It then gets incremented again to 4 by the line `instance.a += 1;` inside `Instance()` before it's returned.

```cpp
std::cout << foo2.a << std::endl; // prints 4
```

Thus, `foo2.a` is 4, which reflects the state of the static instance after the two increments, plus the increment that occurred when `foo2` was created.

If you want `foo1` to reflect the changes made to the singleton instance, you should declare it as a reference:

```cpp
auto& foo1 = Foo::Instance();
```

This way, any changes made to the singleton instance through any means will be reflected in `foo1` since `foo1` would be a reference to the singleton instance, not a separate object.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

`auto foo1 = ...` creates a copy of the instance. You should use `auto& foo1 = ...` if you want to use the same instance, and do the same for `foo2`.